# Are minor versions of Laravel 6.x consider LTS?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm considering using Laravel 6.5 for my next project, however, I want to make sure it will be considered as a long term support version. 
[Laravel's documentation for version 6.x](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/releases) has a table that shows the version 6 as LTS but it doesn't say anything about the minor versions of 6.
So my question is: can I use 6.5 and still receive the LTS? or like the older way of Laravel versioning like how it works across the 5.x version; If 5.5 is LTS 5.6 is not necessarily LTS.

Comment: Laravel 6 is Laravel 6.x ... it no longer follows the same numbering as previous versions (where 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, etc were all different versions) .. the next version of Laravel will be 7

Comment: Thanks, @lagbox!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of Laravel 6.x is LTS as it is all Laravel 6. In Laravel 6, Laravel changes the versioning scheme to get away from the previous style where minor version numbers were acting like major versions (5.1, 5.2, 5.3, etc were all their own versions).

Laravel now follows semver, [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/).